# jquery, how to define a dom template and use it over and over again

Tags: jquery

How do I use some dom as a template, so something like

```
<div>
    <span> v1 </span>
    <span> v2 </span>
    <span> v3 </span>
</div>
```

and then programmatically replace v1-v3 with some values (that i get off an xhr repsonse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply store it as a `string`, then drop it in a jQuery object whenever you need a new copy.

Once it is part of a jQuery object, you can traverse it just like it was already in the DOM, and update its content.

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/bZz96/

```
var div_template = "<div><span> v1 </span><span> v2 </span><span> v3 </span></div>";

$(div_template).find('span')
    .text( function(i) { return 'some new value ' + i; } )
    .end().appendTo('body');
```

Comment: ah excellent.  I didn't realize that jquery could take a string and traverse it like it would the dom already in the page....sweet.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
$template = $('<div><span>v1</span><span>v2</span><span>v3</span></div>');

$new_dom_element = $template.clone();
// do your thing with replacing the content.
```

Answer (score 0):

[Mustache.js](http://github.com/janl/mustache.js/) is really good for this.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft is building a JQuery plugin (it might be incorporated into JQuery) for templates.

[Microsoft, jQuery, and Templating](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2010/03/16/microsoft-jquery-and-templating.aspx)

I'm still waiting to see if anything happens with it, but it seems promising. I just looked at the github repository and it looks like there have been some recent changes (within the last several days), so it's still in progress.